# do not display pop up window while navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page a pop up window display of confirmation only when am going to close the browser/tab. It works for my page but it also ask while am going to navigate to another page. I want the pop up window when i close tab not while navigating to another page. Can anyone plz help me.
Here is code.

```
var PreventExitPop = false;
function ExitPop() { 
    if(PreventExitPop == false) {     
        PreventExitPop=true;
        window.alert("hi!\n\click ok to go on  next page");     
        var frm = document.forms['exitpopform'];    
        frm.action = 'deals.html';     
        frm.submit();     
        scroll(0, 0);     
        return "\n\n\n***************************************\n\n"; 
    }
}  
window.onbeforeunload = ExitPop;
</SCRIPT>
<form id='exitpopform' method='post' action='#'>
  <input type='hidden'  value='' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below Code for this.**

`<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a").click(function () {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            });
            $(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
                return confirm("Do you really want to close?");
            });
        })
    </script>`

- Above code will set **`NULL`** for `onbeforeunload` when any `anchor` tag is cliked throughout the website.
- And if user will **close browser/tab** than it will raise the  **`onbeforeunload`** function and it will show the popup with warning message.
- For this this function you have to add **`JQuery`** reference into **`<head>`** tag of you **`HTML`** page as below.

`<script src="your folder name/Javascript/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`